# colspan and collapse for the same header - possible?

Tags: grid, dhtmlx

I am currently developing a table using dhtmlx grid. I need to achieve the below table construction. I tried many way to achieve this but I wasn't able to apply the colspan and collapse for the same `td` element in the header.

Please check the attachment and help me to get the exact output.

[image]

Comment: Could you please show your code? What did you try?

Comment: Sorry, Since the data are fetched from the back-end which is confidential, I couldn't able to show my codes. Could you please share if you have any suggestions to achieve the exact behavior as in the above screenshot attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such output is not available using the column_collapse extension.
But you can place any html content in your header and hide the required columns on clicking it.
As a draft:

```
    function hiding(){
    if (!collapse){
    myGrid.setColumnHidden(2,true)
    myGrid.setColumnHidden(3,true)
    myGrid.setColumnHidden(4,true)
    document.getElementById("collapse").value="show"
    collapse=true
    }
    else
    {
            myGrid.setColumnHidden(3,true)
    myGrid.setColumnHidden(2,false)
    myGrid.setColumnHidden(3,false)
    myGrid.setColumnHidden(4,false)
    document.getElementById("collapse").value="hide"
    collapse=false
    }
}

        myGrid.setHeader("<input type='button' id='collapse' value='hide' onclick='(arguments[0]||window.event).cancelBubble=true;hiding()'>,#cspan,#cspan,#cspan,#cspan");
        myGrid.attachHeader("1,2,3,4,5")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will check this by next week only and let you know then.